# Invariance of a bilinear (in generators) under a subgroup of a Lie group

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, finite-groups, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $L^a$ be generators of a Lie algebra of a compact connected Lie group $G$ in some irrep ($a$ indexes the generators). Let $\phi_k^a$ be the standard [exponential coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map_(Lie_theory)) for a group element $k$. Consider the following sum of group elements in *any* subgroup $K\subseteq G$ (sums over $a,b$ implied):

$$
\sum_{k\in K} \exp{(\phi^a_k L^a)}
$$

This sum is proportional to the projection onto any trivial irreps of $K$ in the irrep of $G$, so it is invariant under any conjugation by $r \in K$.

Let's expand it in the generators, obtaining the following quadratic leading-order term (the linear term cancels since for any $k\in K$, the inverse is also in the sum):

$$
\left(\sum_{k\in K}\phi_{k}^{a}\phi_{k}^{b}\right)L^{a}L^{b}\equiv f^{ab}L^{a}L^{b}
$$

I conjecture that the above quantity is *also* invariant under conjugation by $r \in K$.

Note that the matrix $f$ is a sum over outer products of the *coordinates* of the subgroup elements, acting on the space of the adjoint irrep of $G$. Under conjugation by $r\in K$, the generators transform as $L^a \to R^{ab} L^b$, where $R=\text{ad}(r)$. So what I think is true is that the matrix $f$ is invariant under conjugation by such rotations.

I've shown this for all subgroups of $K\subset SO_3$, discrete and continuous. If the adjoint irrep of $SO_3$ branches to only one irrep of $K$, it's simple: $f^{ab}\propto\delta^{ab}$. For $K=Z_N$ (rotations around the $z$-axis by multiples of $2\pi/N$), $f \propto \text{diag}(0,0,1)$, which makes sense since the $\phi^a$ are proportional to the axis of rotation. I have neither found a counter-example for other groups nor have I proven this more generally. I suspect the sum can also be over a class instead of a subgroup.

Comment: Is this result independent of the choice of $\phi^a_k$, or is there some special way of choosing them? It seems to me that the tensor will depend of the choice of logarithm.

Comment: My limited intuition tells me they all have to be in the same "branch", because ad($r$) can't change the length $\phi^a \phi^a$. For SO(3), I used the angle-axis representation for $\phi$, taking them all out of a ball of radius $\pi$ with antipodal points on its surface identified. Ad($r$) doesn't respect this surface identification ($\sum_{k\inK} \phi_k$ is *not* invariant), but because $f$ consists of outer products of $\phi$'s, any wrong signs cancel and it all magically works out!

Comment: Is there a generalization of the $SO(3)$ angle-axis representation to all compact connected $G$? Maybe this could help with proving this. I'm even OK with making $G$ simply connected.

Comment: Does something like the Cartan decomposition give you what you need to generalize?

Comment: Looking at the octahedral subgroup $S_4\subset SO(3)$, and choosing a $90^\circ$ rotation $R\in S_4$, if we replace $\phi^a_R$ with $5\phi^a_R$, i think that breaks ad-invariance.

Comment: As for generalizing axis-angle, one could choose the the logarithm corresponding to the minimizing geodesic w.r.t. some canonical left invariant metric, but even then, there are ambiguities which can't be nicely dealt with, such as the antipodal map in $-1\in SO(4)$.

Comment: @Kajelad, thanks for sticking with me. So we're on the same page (since I'm not sure what you mean by replacing), here is what I did for octahedral (https://sites.google.com/site/victorvalbert/physics/oct.png). First line is the Euler angles, second is the conversion into axis-angle, and third is the constructed f matrix. You can see it's $\propto$ identity, so ad-invariance holds. Do you mean that if I change coordinates, I won't get this lucky?

Comment: Yes. The replacement amounts to changing to a set of coordinates which is not as rotationally symmetric, so that one of the elements has a different coordinate with the same image under $\exp$. As another example, if you do the same computation for the octahedral subgroup lifted into $SU(2)$ via the universal covering map, it won't be possible to choose an axis-angle representation of $-1\in SU(2)$ that does not break rotational symmetry.

Comment: @Kajelad, thanks for helping me find an example (with $-1\in SU(2)$) for which my naive expansion didn't work. BTW, shifting the origin of all of the group elements consistently didn't produce any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way around the problem of non-unique coordinates in the expansion is to manually average out the group element over the group before expanding. For each $k\in K$, pick a particular coordinate to represent it; let's say we use one for which $\phi^a_k \phi_k^a$ is minimized. Then, on the group level, use invariance of the sum under conjugation by $h\in K$ to write:

$$
\sum_{k\in K}e^{\phi_{k}^{a}L^{a}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{k\in K}e^{\phi_{k}^{a}L^{a}}+\sum_{k\in K}e^{\phi_{h^{-1}kh}^{a}L^{a}}\right)=\cdots=\frac{1}{|K|}\sum_{k,h\in K}e^{\phi_{h^{-1}kh}^{a}L^{a}}
$$

Expanding the above sum then yields a second order term that is invariant basically by definition. Letting $R_k=\text{ad}(k)$ and shortening $R^{ab}\phi^b \equiv R\phi$, the relevant part of the second-order term reads

$$
\sum_{k,h\in K}\left(R_{k}\phi_{h}\right)^{a}\left(R_{k}\phi_{h}\right)^{b}L^{a}L^{b}
$$

Conjugating by $r\in K$, we can then use the finite group re-summation property to check the invariance:

$$
\sum_{k,h\in K}\left(R_{r}R_{k}\phi_{h}\right)^{a}\left(R_{r}R_{k}\phi_{h}\right)^{b}=\sum_{k,h\in K}\left(R_{rk}\phi_{h}\right)^{a}\left(R_{rk}\phi_{h}\right)^{b}=\sum_{k,h\in K}\left(R_{k}\phi_{h}\right)^{a}\left(R_{k}\phi_{h}\right)^{b}
$$

Same thing can be done on the level of classes.